# Bitbucket pipelines with different build variables

Tags: build, environment-variables, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a simple Vue.js project that utilizes Vite to build the distribution. I am utilizing dotenv to target specific environments for my deployment via different .env files such as **.env** and **.env.dev** where **.env** may contain

```
VITE_APP_TITLE=My Site (local)
```

and .env.dev might contain

```
VITE_APP_TITLE=My Site (dev)
```

Running `vite build` and `vite build --mode dev` generates the correct distribution with the appropriate substitutions, however, I cannot seem to get a similar behavior from Bitbucket pipelines.

My build pipeline currently looks like this

```
image: node:14

pipelines:
  branches: 
    develop:
      - step:
          name: Build and Test
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - npm install
            # - npm test
      - step:
          name: Run build
          script:
            - npm install
            - npm run build:dev
          artifacts:
            - dist/**
          caches:
            - node
      - step:
          name: Deploy to dev
          deployment: dev            
          script:
            - echo "Deploying to dev environment"
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-s3-deploy:0.3.8
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
                S3_BUCKET: $AWS_BUCKET
                LOCAL_PATH: 'dist'
                ACL: 'public-read'
      - step:
          name: Invalidate Cloudfront Cache
          script:      
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-cloudfront-invalidate:0.6.0
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION            
                DISTRIBUTION_ID: $AWS_DISTRIBUTION_ID
                PATHS: "/index.html"
```

I am utilizing the repository "Deployments" setting to add variables for the deployment stage but there does not appear to be a way for me to access these for the build stage as the **deployment:** setting can only be used during one stage of the pipeline. Has anyone figured out a way to account for different build environment variables during the build stage of the pipeline that could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want full control, you would need to go with [custom steps and variables](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-bitbucket-pipelinesyml/#variables). But this doesn't allow for easy automation.

So for automation it is about question on when the deployment end would change? If it's based on the branch/tag, then you would just do a separate pipeline with the settings hardcoded into it per different deployment. If it's all going thru the same way, then you are more limited on how to control it.